# How to get distinct and lastest record with inner join query

Tags: sql, ms-access, inner-join

I have two table named: **customers** and **bill**. customer and bill have one to many relation.
Customer table contains record of customer mobileNo,bikeNo etc
Bill table contain record of customer bill with bikeNo(foreign key),billdate etc.
I have query for that:

```
SELECT        customer.mobileNo, bill.iDate AS Expr1
FROM            (customer INNER JOIN
                     bill ON customer.bikeNo = bill.bikeNo)
ORDER BY bill.iDate;
```

Now How i get distinct and latest billdate record and mobileNo with this query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use GROUP BY and MAX():

```
SELECT customer.mobileNo, MAX(bill.iDate) AS iDate
FROM (customer INNER JOIN
                 bill ON customer.bikeNo = bill.bikeNo)
GROUP BY customer.mobileNo
ORDER BY iDate
```